# Is there any problem with praying the same salah twice?

Tags: salat, jamaat

I have 2 cases two discuss.

1. I offered my salah well within time at my home, alone. I walked out of my house and saw a few of my friends who were going to the masjid to pray the same salah as a group (jamaat). I joined them and prayed the same salah again as a member of the group.
2. I offered my salah. But my mind was not in it. I am not sure if I prayed 3 or 4 rakahs. Not sure if I did the two sujoods or not. Feeling discontent, I offered it again.

Are these actions fine within Islam? Is it makrooh/mushtabbh to do so? Please answer with evidences/references.

Answer (score 3):

Case number 1 seems fine according to this Hadith

> Jabir bin Yazid bin Al-Aswad Al Amir told us that his father said: "I
>   attended Fajr prayer with the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ)in Masjid Al
>   Khaif. When he finished praying, he saw two men at the back of the
>   people who had not prayed with him. He said: 'Bring them here.' So
>   they were brought to him, trembling. He said: 'What kept you from
>   praying with us? They said: '0 Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) we has already
>   prayed in our lodgings.' He said: 'Do not do that. If you have already
>   prayed in your lodgings, then you come to a Masjid in which there is a
>   congregation, then pray with them, and it will be a voluntary prayer
>   for you."'

```
Grade   : Sahih (Darussalam)    
Reference: Sunan an-Nasa'i 858
In-book reference: Book 10, Hadith 82
English translation: Vol. 1, Book 10, Hadith 859
```

Case # 2:
If you forget Salah you should do Sajada Sahaw

Reference when you forget something
http://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/619

Don't feel discontent when you are performing things according to Sahih Hadiths